# How to reduce ionic checkboxes event width

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, checkbox

I have recently got to update a Ionic App.

On its forms, every checkbox has the same behavior:
No matter the size of the row, each one of them is clickable or their full width, not only on the checkbox module.

I can't get how it works, and if I can change this, in order to have the clicking event triggered only on the checkbox, and not on the full row.

Here's a simple playground that show the behavior: http://play.ionic.io/app/72d2ce2d0816

Comment: Are you sure your app works? For example `ng-click="alert(1)"` doesn't work on your checkbox.

Comment: I don't think you can use alert in ng-click if you didn't declare this function in this scope before